# Foundry Scenarios edited data materialized as dataset

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-scenarios

Is it possible to materialize the edits made as part of a scenario into a dataset in foundry?

I want for each scenario to write out the primary keys of the objects edited as part of the scenario.

The motivation is that I need to run multiple processes to compute metrics as part of the changed values for each scenario, at a scale and runtime that is not possible to do with Functions.

**Edit with details:**

The thing is that I am not doing actual edits to the objects for the object type, I don't want to apply it.

I tested out the "Action Log" and it does not seem like this picks up "uncommitted" actions, meaning actions that is just run as part of a scenario. Also, it does not seem to be a link to the scenario it was a part of, even if the changes were committed.

The workflow is that I have Object Type A, and I define multiple scenarios S on a subset of the objects in A.

Each scenario might make something like 50k edits to a subset of A, through multiple Actions backed by a Function.

I save some of the scenarios. Now I am able to load these scenarios and "apply" them on A again in Workshop.

However I need to be able to get all the primary keys, and the edited values of A materialized into a dataset (for each scenario), as I need to run some transformation logic to compute a metric for the change as part of each scenario (at a scale and execution time not possible in Functions).

The Action Log did not seem to help a lot for this. How do I get the "edits" as part of a saved scenario into a dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik there's no first class way of doing this (yet).

"Applying" a scenario basically means you're submitting the actions queued on the scenario to the ontology. So neither the actions nor the ontology are aware that they came from a scenario.

What I've been doing to achieve what you're working on is using the "Action Log". It's still in Beta so you might need to ask for it to be enabled. It will allow you on each action to define a "log" object to be created that can track the pks of your edited objects per Action.

How I do the action log is:

My Action log has the "timestamp" of the action when they were run.
My Scenarios have the "timestamp" of when it was applied.

Since "Applying a Scenario" means -> actually running all actions on Ontology (underlying data) this gets me this structure if I sort everything by timestamp:

- Action 1
- Action 2
- Scenario A applied
- Action 3
- Action 4
- Scenario B applied

this allows you to do a mapping later on of Action 1/2 must come from Scenario A and Action 3+4 come from Scenario B.

---

**EDIT:** Apparently you might be able to use the Scenario RID directly in the Action Logs too (which is a recent addition I haven't adopted yet)

---

This won't allow you tho to compute (in transforms...) anything BEFORE applying a scenario tho

Comment: I updated the question with some additional detail, as the Action Log did not seem to help too much in my case

Comment: I see. You basically want to compute something BEFORE the scenario is "applied".
The problem here is that all these "edits" are calculate "on the fly" (your scenario loading) and are not persisted or stored. So I don't see a way you could access them from anywhere else unfortunately.

Comment: Also edited my initial answer to clarify how I use action logs

Comment: By "apply" to you mean to commit the edited objects to the Ontology? In my workflow would never want to commit the edits. Action Log did not seem to produce data in the writeback when just triggering actions as part of a scenario, is that correct? Do you need to write back?

What I would like to is to define a scenario, which is done through an ontology edit function on subsets of these objects, save that scenario. and for each scenario run a longer computation process (volatility over time, monte carlo simulation process...) something that is not possible to do in Functions .

Comment: What you might want to do is run a model on your scenario: [Docs for Models on Scenarios here](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/workshop/scenarios-select-model/)

This runs on your scenario after all actions have been applied and edits have been made. Again you won't know exactly what these edits are (by default - might be able to figure out using action logs but def hacky) and you only have access to the current state of the data in your scenario (not "master").


You can code your model in python and do a bunch of more complicated stuff there or even load an external model.

Comment: This is what I would prefer, but this is a SaaS/"cloud only" feature as far as I have understood, and out platform is running on an on premise datacenter.

I do not really need to know exactly what the edits are. I just need access to the new value of the primary keys after the edits from the scenario

Comment: Also, some of the things I want to recompute on top of the scenario are longer running simulation processes that might take up to 20 minutes for each scenario. Every time I open the app and select a scenario I don't want to wait for this compute to happen, for each scenario. Therefore it would make a lot of sense if I could materialize this scenario somehow such that I can run a pipeline on each of the scenarios to compute the relevant values I need about the effects of the scenario and store those against the scenario object

Comment: Ah I was not aware you were on prem. You are correct these features are currently not available on prem. To your second comment - we're tracking this workflow to run transform logic directly on scenario data, very early scoping + development has started to make this possible but please be advised that this won't be available any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

The only logic you can run BEFORE applying will be functions.

Not sure about your exact logic but Function's Custom Aggregations can be very powerful: [Docs here](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/functions/create-custom-aggregation/)

this might not directly let you calculate the Diff but you could use the scenario compare widgets in workshop to compare your aggregation between multiple Scenarios

e.g. you have a function that sums(total profit)

Your Workshop could show:

```
Current Data:
$10k
Scenario A:
$5k
Scneario B:
$13k
```

instead of like:

```
Scenario A:
-$5k
Scenario B:
+$3k
```

Comment: Functions aggregations are sadly a bit limited for my workflow. After editing objets in the scenario I have to take a 150k size object set(and 100k is a limitation), aggregate it into aggregations to about 40k groups, join in data from another Object Type with a foreign key to these groups, and then compute the metrics that I need.

Comment: Usually just the required filtering and loading the full size of the initial dataset takes too long and the Function times out after 30 seconds. The aggregations in typescript and some of the computations to produce outputs usually runs quite fast, but loading the data takes too long.

Comment: It would be great if I could run an aggregation to get the values for the 40k groups, but currently there seems to be a limit of 1000 groups, which is why I first need to load all the data in memory (which I even can't because of the 100k limit, and then run the aggregation in JS code.